# How to get response from any ip address in angular 7

Tags: angular, request, response, angular7

I want to get any kind of response by sending request to different ip-addresses

```
export class DeviceComponent implements OnInit {

  response: any
  constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceService.ping().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}

export class DeviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ping() {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    })

    let me: string = `http://192.168.10.7:100`
    let aw: string = `http://192.168.10.6:100`
    let google: string = `https://www.google.com`
    let youtube: string = `https://www.youtube.com`

    return this.http.get(google, {
      headers: httpHeaders
    })
  }

}
```

Problem I am facing is that when I send request to `youtube` or `google`, I get response

[image]

but when I send request to some `local-ip`, I get response

[image]

**Actually my main aim is to get response from local ips**

### Update

What if I want to get response from my pc on which this app I am developing, let say I have ip: `192.168.9.9`. Sending request to my pc but `connection refused`, then 
What should be configured?

Please guide!!!

Comment: seems`CORS` issue it is

Comment: google is not accepting connection from your IP

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes, but setting headers, am I setting wrong?

Comment: What about local ip, how can I get response?

Comment: This should be on backend side too, otherwise it will not work

Comment: CORS issue should be fixed by server side not by angular

Comment: Please check question, I have updated

Comment: you should just set up local server and run your backend application on port 5000 for example. Then you can maker request like `this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')` without any configuration on frontend part.

Comment: how is your server set up anyway ?

Comment: No server, only client app and I need to `locate-local-devices` by pinging or whatever method is used in angular

Answer (score 0):

We seem to have two different Issues here:

On the one hand you try to access **http://www.google.com** which gets Blocked because of the CORS-Policy ([see here](https://spring.io/understanding/CORS)).
This is probably the same when accessing **http://www.youtube.com**

On the other hand you try to access a local IP. The connection can get refused because of different reason. Either your server/computer is not reachable or there is something else going wrong. Try to ping your computer first with cmd `ping 192.168.9.9`. If this is not reachable, try to configure your Firewall (on both devices).
Check if the port is correctly set and your server is runnning and reachable from the server itself.
Its difficult to say more without additional Information.

Comment: I can ping my pc via terminal and it is OK

Comment: Test your Server with an API Testing-Tool. For Example:  https://www.getpostman.com/apps If you reach your Server with this and get proper responses, you can try with your client